# PValueError while am comparing string is in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, boto3

I Get ValueError:

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

def translate_complaints(my_dataframe):

```
for index, row in my_dataframe.iterrows():
    desc = my_dataframe.loc[index, 'description']
    if desc != '':
        resp = translate.translate_text(Text=desc,
                                        SourceLanguageCode='auto',
                                        TargetLanguageCode='en')

        my_dataframe.loc[index, 'description'] = resp['TranslatedText']
return my_dataframe
```

### ValueError : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

if (desc != '').any():

return this error :

Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Text, value: 0    these folks planted some bushes between the si...

Name: description, dtype: object, type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

DF exple:

ticket_id          enteredDate  ...   latitude  longitude

0       154746  2016-08-11 11:04:29  ...  39.169525 -86.474846

1       154772  2016-08-12 09:09:35  ...  39.175426 -86.537888

2       154933  2016-08-17 14:37:56  ...        NaN        NaN

3       154935  2016-08-17 15:27:49  ...  39.161301 -86.538101

[4152089 rows x 15 columns]

Comment: can you provide an example dataframe that throws this error?

Comment: done, added to the question

Comment: try `df.sample(n=30).to_dict()`.   It's hard to debug if we can't use your dataframe.

Comment: the dataframe contains 13 columns, and am just working with 1 column which is 'description'  which contains users complaints |||-->Street light not working, large potholes, bad sidewalk .. <--|||
and i wanted to check if the column is not empty to apply a translation to english.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, within your translate function, the Text=desc is getting a series and not a value. The index AND description columns are being passed and it only wants the description.

maybe try .at instead of .loc

```
desc = my_dataframe.at[index, 'description']
```

Also, you may want to reduce what you are doing by just collecting rows that have data due to the large size of the df.

```
df_to_translate = my_dataframe.loc[my_dataframe['description'] != '']
```

Once you do this you can iterate here, or look into use of .apply(). There are other methods that are faster than itterrows.